# How to show just a progress bar during a preseeded installation?

Tags: installation, preseed

Based on the comment on [a question on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/296085/ubuntu-in-silent-mode/296088#296088), I started wondering if it's possible to show a progress bar with no text during an installation.

That could be used to provide a user-friendly installation for computer illiterate for which a few lines can be very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting. You can decide what to show and what to not show in some UI property files. At last, I have found the path. Is in usr/share/ubiquity/gtk/. You just have to set some parameters in the screen you want to use. For example I needed to deactivate labels so i have set all GtkLabels in visible=False.

Hope this information helps others! Kind regards.

PS: This "no text" mode should exists in ubuntu in some place. Maybe an improvement to next versions. Bye